# Why do the sets in the Borel-Lebesgue covering theorem need to be closed?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I understand the converse theorem that if every open coverage of a set admits a finite subcoverage then that set is compact; that is, I understand (or at least I think I do) why that condition "forces" the set to be closed. But where does the fact that the set is closed intervene in proving that every open coverage of a compact set admits a finite subcoverage?
The proof that I have seen makes use of a Lindelof theorem that ensures a enumerable subcoverage of every open coverage, and then reasons that the intersections of the set with the complement of successive reunions of the elements of the subcoverage provide a decreasing succession of sets which, in the limit, intersect to the empty set, and by Cantor's property there must be some member of the succession that is the empty set ie you needed a finite number of the elements of the subcoverage to cover the set. Perhaps stated more clearly, let $K$ be the compact set in question and $A_{\lambda_i}$, $i \in {1,2,...}$ the enumerable subcoverage. Putting $K_n=K \cap C(A_{\lambda_1} \cup ... \cup  A_{\lambda_n})$, we see that the $K_n$ intersect to the empty set, seeing as there is no point that is in all of them, and by Cantor's property, for some $n$, $K_n$ must be empty. Where does the closeness of K enter the picture?

Comment: Doesn't Cantor's theorem require the sets $K_n$ to be closed?

Comment: @Mason yeah but does that require K itself to be closed as well?

Comment: I like this topic, but I wish you'd include above the statements of your theorems: "Borel-Lebesgue covering" and "Cantor's"

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo If $K$ is not closed, then how are you going to how that $K_n$ is closed? If $K$ is closed then $K_n$ is closed since it is an intersection of closed sets

Comment: @Mason if K is closed, K of n will surely be closed. But I ask further if the closeness of K is necessary. Surely the K of n may be closed without K itself being closed. But maybe that would depend in an unpredictable way on the subcoverage?

Comment: @311411 I refrained from adding then in fear that the question would get too stuffy, but I'll get to adding those statements then.

Comment: Which definition of compactness do you use?

Comment: You could link to statements of the Theorems for brevity, but I think you should include a fairly self-contained problem statement in the body of your Question, one that can be read without essential reliance on the title wording.  Brevity is good style but not at the expense of having a problem statement (setup and goal) that Readers can easily parse.  Breaking up your "wall of text" with paragraphs and other whitespace would also help.  I could try my hand at it if you are interested.